# Register post status, exclude from searches

Tags: posts, hooks

I am trying to register a new post type to hide post in searches but still allow for the post to be seen by url.

```
function reg_ghost_status(){
    register_post_status( 'ghosted', array(
        'label'                     => 'Ghost Post',
        'publicly_queryable'        => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        'public'                    => true, //on false hides everywhere
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'reg_ghost_status' );
```

I could not get this work and tried all sorts of combinations. It seems since it is 'public' it shows everywhere no matter what settings. So I than tried using the pre_set_query but I don't know how to use exclude instead of include by post_status.

```
function sxcsexclude_ghost_from_search($query) {
        if ( $query->is_single ) {
             $query->set('perm', 'readable');
             $query->set('post_status', array( 'publish', 'draft', 'ghosted', 'future' ));
            return $query;
        }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', '11111exclude_ghost_from_search' );
```

Can someone tell me why the register_post_status is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is registering a post status, not a post type. Try [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) instead.

Comment: Sorry I typed posttype but I did mean status

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would probably just override the queries on the individual templates that you are trying to hide "ghosted" posts on. However, I can see how in some situations it would be better to override the main query.

How about:

```
function public_query_published_only($query) {
  if ( !$query->is_single() && !current_user_can('manage_options') && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_status', array('publish') );
        return $query;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'public_query_published_only' );
```

So: if the query is not for a single post, and the user isn't a logged-in user, and the query isn't from the admin interface, only show posts with a status of "publish". (Of course, you could also add any other statuses that you deem to be query-able.)

Because there is not an exclusion filter for post status, this is the best I could think of without resorting to SQL.

Comment: Yes I think manipulating the query is going to be the only way. I'm just confused why the arguments for register_post_status aren't working, specifically exclude_from_search.

Comment: Would like to add I found that the API hasn't been finished for 10+ years which might have something to do with it. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706

Comment: @Tianbo84 What post type are you using the "ghost" status on? If the post type is allowed to show up in search, I don't think the post *status* is going to override that setting. So that might be where your conflict is.

Comment: post type is just 'post'. Do you mean if in the original query it has post_type => post?

Comment: I was just wondering if you were using it on the default 'post' type, or a custom post type. After some thought, and after looking at that ticket you linked to: perhaps you would be better off using a custom field, such as "ghosted", and then modifying the query to skip over posts that include that custom field. This seems to make more logical sense, since the post is technically published, it just is not displayed in archives/search.

Comment: Yes I have been playing with it and that did cross my mind. I may just do that since the exclude option isn't working as I thought it would. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

This question asked long time ago, but here is the better solution:

```
add_action( 'posts_where', function( $where, $q ) {
    if( $q->is_search() ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $status_to_exclude = 'ghosted';   // Modify this to your needs!

        $where .= sprintf( 
            " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status NOT IN ( '%s' ) ", 
            $status_to_exclude 
        );

    }
    return $where;
}, 10, 2 );
```